# Java generic type with wildcard

Tags: java, generics

I want to write a method that can accept the parameter:

```
Map<String, [the type here could be anything]>
```

So, here is what I coded:

```
/**
 * Get list value from a map, empty list if there's no key matched 
 */
private List<? extends Object> getListValueFromMap(Map<String, List<? extends Object>> map, String key) {
    List<? extends Object> list = map.get(key);
    return list == null ? EMPTY_LIST : list;
}
```

And the `EMPTY_LIST` is defined as below:

```
List<Object> EMPTY_LIST = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<Object>());
```

The problem is that when I call this method with following code, Eclipse tells me a error that the given parameter's type is not applicable.

```
getListValueFromMap(cityNameMap, "key");
```

And the error is:

> `The method getListValueFromMap(Map<String,List<? extends Object>>, String) in the type ChinaAreaResource is not applicable for the arguments (Map<String,List<City>>, String)`

Where am I going wrong with this?

Here is the definition of `cityNameMap`:

```
/** map city's name to city list */
private Map<String, List<City>> cityNameMap;
```

Comment: How is `citiNameMap` defined?

Comment: Being **cityNameMap** like this `Map<String, List<? extends Object>> cityNameMap = null;` for me works fine.

Comment: What’s the point of `Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<Object>());`? If you already know about `Collections`, why don’t you use `Collections.emptyList()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's important to take note of what `? extends Object` actually represents in generics.

In its current incantation, it is an [upper-bounded wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) which has its upper bound as `Object`.  Ideally, this would *imply* that you could use any list from it, but since generics are invariant, that wouldn't be the case here at all - you could only use lists which have the same bound.

Since the containing type of the list may change from map to map, set your bound on a generic type to get at the list you care about instead.

```
private <T> List<? extends T> getListValueFromMap(Map<String, List<T>> map, String key) {
    List<? extends T> list = map.get(key);
    return list == null ? EMPTY_LIST : list;
}
```

Be sure to update your `EMPTY_LIST` dependency accordingly; obviously in this state, you can't return the list bounded with `Object`.

This has the advantage of allowing you to pass your list in with *any* supplied type, and you won't be able to simply add elements to it once you retrieve them from your map due to the way the generic argument is done on the list.

Comment: I think I somewhat understand your words, since the compiler can't tell the real type of <? extends T>, it only allow T type retrieved from it.

Comment: The correct idiom for the empty list is `Collections.<T>emptyList()` which will still return the singleton `Collections.EMPTY_LIST`, but now without the need to suppress “unchecked” warnings. Starting with Java 8, you can elide the `<T>` and just use `Collections.emptyList()`. By the way, Generics aren’t invariant in all cases, so using `Map<String, ? extends List<?>>` as parameter type would solve the issue as well, but adding the type parameter `<T>` to declare that the returned list has the same element type as the `Map` value’s type is much better.

Comment: By the way, there is no benefit in converting the map’s `List<T>` to a `List<? extends T>` in the process. You can just return `List<T>`…

Comment: @Holger:  Yes, but the OP appeared to want that list to be a producer with the way their generics were set up, so I simply preserved that behavior.  The key difference between `List<T>` and `List<? extends T>` is that you can't add elements to the latter; you can only retrieve them.

Comment: You shouldn’t rely on immutability made by Generic signatures. `Collections.swap` still can be called with such a list and so can `remove`. So I recommend following [Oracle’s advice](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html): “*Using a wildcard as a return type should be avoided because it forces programmers using the code to deal with wildcards.*”

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
private <T> List<T> getListValueFromMap(Map<String, List<T>> map, String key) {
    //
}
```

Both don't give me any issues in my IDE (IntelliJ 2016.1.1), but it could be that yours has different settings.

Comment: Yes, that's can fix my problem, only I cannot return the EMPTY_LIST from the method, unless I leave the return type unchanged, but I think the real reason maybe in that there's some design problems to return only a singleton instance of List<Object> no matter the caller give me what type of List within parameter Map

Comment: And still I'm very carious about the reason why I can't call the method originally~

Comment: public static final List EMPTY_LIST = new ArrayList(); works fine for me

Comment: If you still want to use your code, see Makoto's answer for more info. You can try declaring your cityNameMap like so: Map<String, List<? extends Object>> cityNameMap